# Why is mutable and extra scope needed

Tags: rust

I want to print out the parameters passed to the FastCGI application:

```
extern crate fastcgi; // 1.0.0

use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    fastcgi::run(|mut req| {
        let mut output = String::from("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");

        {
            let mut params = req.params();

            loop {
                let param = params.next();

                match param {
                    Some(t) => output.push_str(&format!("{:?}", t)),
                    None => break,
                }
            }
        }

        write!(&mut req.stdout(), "{}", &output).unwrap_or(());
    });
}
```

My code works but I don't understand why I need to do it that way. My intuition is that I could write this non-working code:

```rust
extern crate fastcgi; // 1.0.0

use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    fastcgi::run(|mut req| {
        let mut output = String::from("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
        let mut params = req.params();
        loop {
            let param = params.next();
            match param {
                Some(t) => output.push_str(&format!("{:?}", t)),
                None => break,
            }
        }
        write!(&mut req.stdout(), "{}", &output).unwrap_or(());
    });
}
```

Compiler Output:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `req` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
8  |         let mut params = req.params();
   |                          --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |         write!(&mut req.stdout(), "{}", &output).unwrap_or(());
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
17 |     });
   |     - immutable borrow might be used here, when `params` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = (std::string::String, std::string::String)>>`
```

I found the solution by Googling around and following suggestions of the compiler, but I don't understand why it is necessary.

Comment: *immutable borrow might be used here, when `params` is dropped and runs the destructor for type* — seems like the compiler is already explaining the problem to you

Comment: You probably want `for t in req.params() { output.push_str(&format!("{:?}", t)); }`

Comment: What do i have to do, that `params` won't get dropped if I use `&` it does still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [`Request::params`](https://docs.rs/fastcgi/1.0.0/fastcgi/struct.Request.html#method.params) it is defined as:

```
pub fn params(&self) -> Params
```

that is deceptively simple, because `Params` has a hidden lifetime generic. It is actually desugared to:

```
pub fn params<'s>(&'s self) -> Params<'s>
```

That means that as long as the return of this function lives, `self`, that is the `Request`, is considered borrowed.

Similarly the definition of `Request::stdout` is desugared to:

```
pub fn stdout<'s>(&'s mut self) -> Stdout<'s>
```

This method borrows your object mutable, and as you probably know you cannot borrow the same object mutably and non-mutably at the same time.

Writing the extra scope limits the life of `params` and frees the borrow just before calling `stdout` so their lifetimes do not overlap and the code compiles.

If you do not like the extra indentation level you can also write:

```
drop(params);
```

just after the loop to finish the life of `params` manually.

You may think that `params()` and `stdout()` have nothing in common internally and that you should be able to use them mutably at the same time. You might be right, but the compiler does not care, it only sees how these functions are defined, not what they do internally.

Comment: It's possible that the fastcgi crate is just overly conservative. `Params<'a>` is actually a `Box<dyn Iterator + 'a>`, which means (1) it implements `Drop` and (2) the `Drop` implementation might use `'a`. If `Params<'a>` were a type that does not implement `Drop`, it would be fine. Also, if it were a type like `Vec<&'a str>` it would also compile because `&'a str` is not `Drop`, and in `Vec<T>`'s `Drop` implementation `T` is `#[may_dangle]`.

Comment: @trentcl: Nice explanation, the _drop checker_ is always tricky to understand. Naturally if you want a `Vec<&'a str>` you can just do `req.params().collect::<Vec<_>>()`.